# NodeJS, IRC-bot. Something is slowing it down, but what?

Tags: javascript, node.js, irc

Today I just felt like writing an IRC-bot in Javascript with NodeJS. Everything works just fine, but it is bottlenecking somewhere.

For example, when I type a command several times it answers me immediately at first, but then starts to queue up and take longer and longer to respond.

Here's my code http://kl1p.com/ONyw

Comment: We're going to need more information as to what "bottleneck" means. Like, cap on throughput? Also what version of Node are you running? What are the system specs it's running on? etc.

Comment: It is probably just the server-side ratelimiting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I totally forgot about this post. That's what coding drunk does to you!

Anyway, I solved it. It was as caf said, server-side ratelimiting. My local ircd was setup wrong. Working like a charm when it's running in a live environment.

Answer (score 0):

Not seeing anything apparently wrong with your code.

Try debugging it by commenting out parts of it, if at some point you don't see the slowing down you know that commented portion is responsible.

Archaic, but works every time :)